# Issue with hidden div-jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

i'm using jquery hashchange technique for dynamically and smoothly(fadein) loading the contents in a website.Though it's dynamic the url gets changed in the addressbar which looks as follows..as you can see a pound symbol appears before filename.
**www.whatever.com/#about.html**
 **www.whatever.com/#contact.html** and so on.

In my index page a div named **'folder1'** is hidden by default and it's made visible 5seconds after the page is loaded and there is div folder2(check the code). 
When you type url **'www.whatever.com'** everything works as it should. But when you hit **'home'** link it appends **#** to **index.html** so url will be **whatever.com/#index.html**.
And this time div **'folder2'** show up right after page is loaded which should be hidden as per the code. I noticed css of those divs gets messed up this time.
I don't understand what's happpening there. Any help?

```
(function($,i,b){var j,k=$.event.special,c="location",d="hashchange",l="href",f=$.browser,g=document.documentMode,h=f.msie&&(g===b||g<8),e="on"+d in i&&!h;function a(m){m=m||i[c][l];return m.replace(/^[^#]*#?(.*)$/,"$1")}$[d+"Delay"]=100;k[d]=$.extend(k[d],{setup:function(){if(e){return false}$(j.start)},teardown:function(){if(e){return false}$(j.stop)}});j=(function(){var m={},r,n,o,q;function p(){o=q=function(s){return s};if(h){n=$('<iframe src="javascript:0"/>').hide().insertAfter("body")[0].contentWindow;q=function(){return a(n.document[c][l])};o=function(u,s){if(u!==s){var t=n.document;t.open().close();t[c].hash="#"+u}};o(a())}}m.start=function(){if(r){return}var t=a();o||p();(function s(){var v=a(),u=q(t);if(v!==t){o(t=v,u);$(i).trigger(d)}else{if(u!==t){i[c][l]=i[c][l].replace(/#.*/,"")+"#"+u}}r=setTimeout(s,$[d+"Delay"])})()};m.stop=function(){if(!n){r&&clearTimeout(r);r=0}};return m})()})(jQuery,this);

$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

above makes the entire jquery code.

this is the css.infact there are two divs.

```
#folder1{
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 100px;
display: none;
    }
#folder2{
float: left;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 100px;
display: show;
    }
```

below is the code usedto hide and show divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("#folder2").hide(); 

setTimeout(function(){
$("#folder1").show();
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("#folder1").hide();
}, 10000);

setTimeout(function(){
$("#folder2").show();
}, 15000);

});
```

Comment: Could you post a code sample?

Comment: Please post an un-minified version of your js.

Comment: @harsh If you can code and read minified JS, I will genuinely give you five British pounds. Please post your un-minified code :-)

Comment: post the code where you are making the folder div appear after 5 seconds